# Place Circular ImageView on the Edge of another Circular ImageView

Tags: android

I wan to place Small `ImageView` on the anchor  of CircularView   just like below image

[image]

My Code is

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.hey.heypickup.UI.UICircularImage xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                          android:id="@+id/contct_imgpic"
                                          android:layout_width="55dp"
                                          android:layout_height="55dp"
                                          android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                          android:layout_weight="0.04"
                                          android:padding="10dp"
                                          app:line_color="@color/colorPrimary"
                                          app:line_color_press="@color/green"
                                          android:src="@drawable/ph_1"
                                          app:line_width="1dp"
                                          app:padding="0dp"/>


        <ImageView


            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_black"

        />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Result of above code:

[image]

but the Second `imageview` not appearing at the achor of circularImageView?
Can we achieve this without using floating action button ?
if yes then how ?

Comment: where does second `ImageView` showing up if not at the anchor ? Can you share that screenshot ?

Comment: Also, are you sure you're not setting visibility to `gone` or `invisible` for that imageView somewhere in the code ?

Comment: @ Jabbar its overlaping first image

Comment: maybe you can achieve it by extending from imageview and create custom imageview

Comment: @kamran overlapping entirely ? I think it's because your `ImageView` has a `wrap_content` height and width. You should make it a fix size, and try it out because if your `ic_dialog_email` image is large enough then it will take entire space and might overlap the first image

Comment: @masoudvali do you have any example

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo ic_dialog image is not large

Comment: @kamran It looks large to me from the image you just uploaded. Can you make `height` and `width` fix and try again. make it `15dp` each and take a look. Also remove that `margin` from `ImageView` along with that change

Comment: Aah see @kamran you're getting there. Just play around margins and size until you get your expected result. I'm adding my comment as answer so that you may approve it.

Comment: it is an example which extended from imageview http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/10/android-custom-shape-imageview-rounded.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your second image is overlapping the first image,

I think it's because your `ImageView` has a `wrap_content` height and width. You should make it a fix size, and try it out because if your `ic_dialog_email` image is large enough then it will take entire space and might overlap the first image.

Would you make `height` and `width` fix and try again? For example, make it `15dp` each and take a look. Also remove that `margin` from ImageView along with that change.

You'll just need to trial and check the exact size your need for the second image along with required margin to position itself correctly as per your UI requirements